# Dynamics CRM connection through Live service gives error

Tags: wcf, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

Hello I am try to connect CRM online 2016 using Live wcf rest service hosted on Godaddy server But it gives an below error.But it works well in localhost.

Error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceMetadataUtility.RetrieveACSIssuerEndpoints(Uri trustUrl)

   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.SetAuthenticationConfiguration()

   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1..ctor(Uri serviceUri, Boolean checkForSecondary)

   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceConfiguration..ctor(Uri serviceUri, Boolean enableProxyTypes, Assembly assembly)

   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration[TService](Uri serviceUri, Boolean enableProxyTypes, Assembly assembly)

   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration[TService](Uri serviceUri)

   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1..ctor(Uri uri, Uri homeRealmUri, ClientCredentials clientCredentials, ClientCredentials deviceCredentials)

   at PortalRestfulService.Service1.authentication(CRMCredential objauthentication)



WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.

To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.

To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Please suggest me solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try copying your IdentityModel dll's into the bin folder.

But, because probably your WCF service in Godaddy uses a shared application pool and runs in partial trust, and therefore it runs with a limited set of permissions, you'll have other issues.

Try to recompile / retest your service in Partial Trust mode in localhost and you'll probably reproduce the issue.

So the solution would be either:

1. Change your code so it works in Partial trust fine
2. User another hosting options (like a full VM) where you can do pretty much everything you want (like running code in Full Trust, install Identity Model assemblies, etc...).

Comment: Hi It is in full trust mode. There is any other way to solve this?

Comment: Try copying your IdentityModel dll's into the bin folder.